# Coremltools: cannot use some of the outputs from a non-maximum suppression layer in subsequent layers

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, coremltools, non-maximum-suppression

**EDIT:** seems like this is a bug in Coremltools. See here:
https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/691#event-3295066804

---

**one-sentence summary**: the non-maximum suppression layer outputs four values, but I am only able to use two of those four values as inputs to subsequent layers.

I'm building a neural network model using Apple's Core ML Tools package, and I've added a [non-maximum suppression (NMS) layer](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.models.neural_network.builder.html#coremltools.models.neural_network.builder.NeuralNetworkBuilder.add_lrn). This layer has four outputs, per the documentation:

- output 1: box coordinates, corresponding to the surviving boxes.
- output 2: box scores, corresponding to the surviving boxes.
- output 3: indices of the surviving boxes. *[this is the output I want to use in a subsequent layer]*
- output 4: number of boxes selected after the NMS algorithm

I've set up a test model with some simple inputs, and the NMS layer correctly returns the expected values for each of the four outputs listed above. If I then use either output#1 or output#2 in a subsequent layer, I have no problems doing so. However, if I try to use output#3 or output#4 in a subsequent layer, I get an error saying that the input was "not found in any of the outputs of the preceding layers."

### Jupyter Notebook

The easiest way to replicate the issue is to download and go through this [Jupyter Notebook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofi9edy9gz00bta/NMS%20Layer%20Debugger.ipynb?dl=0).

Alternatively, the sample code below also walks through the problem I'm having.

### Sample Code

I've set up some sample input data as follows:

```python
boxes = np.array(
    [[[0.00842474, 0.83051298, 0.91371644, 0.55096077],
      [0.34679857, 0.31710117, 0.62449838, 0.70386912],
      [0.08059154, 0.74079195, 0.61650205, 0.28471152]]], np.float32)

scores = np.array(
    [[[0.87390688],
      [0.2797731 ],
      [0.72611251]]], np.float32)

input_features = [('boxes', datatypes.Array(*boxes.shape)),
                  ('scores', datatypes.Array(*scores.shape))]
output_features = [('output', None)]

data = {'boxes': boxes,
        'scores': scores }
```

And I've built the test model as follows:

```python
builder = neural_network.NeuralNetworkBuilder(input_features, output_features, disable_rank5_shape_mapping=True)

# delete the original output, which was just a placeholder while initializing the model
del builder.spec.description.output[0]

# add the NMS layer
builder.add_nms(
    name="nms",
    input_names=["boxes","scores"],
    output_names=["nms_coords", "nms_scores", "surviving_indices", "box_count"],
    iou_threshold=0.5,
    score_threshold=0.5,
    max_boxes=3,
    per_class_suppression=False)

# make the model output all four of the NMS layer's outputs
for name in ["nms_coords", "nms_scores", "surviving_indices", "box_count"]:
    builder.spec.description.output.add()
    builder.spec.description.output[-1].name = name
    builder.spec.description.output[-1].type.multiArrayType.dataType = ft.ArrayFeatureType.FLOAT32

# # add a linear activation layer (intentionally commented out)
# builder.add_activation(
#     name="identity",
#     non_linearity="LINEAR",
#     input_name="surviving_indices",
#     output_name="activation_output",
#     params=[1.0,0.0])

# initialize the model
model = coremltools.models.MLModel(builder.spec)
```

At this point, when I call

```python
output = model.predict(data, useCPUOnly=True)
print(output)
```

everything works as expected.

For example, if I call `print(output['surviving_indices']`, the result is `[[ 0.  2. -1.]]` (as expected).

However, I'm unable to use either the `surviving_indices` or the `box_count` outputs as an input to a subsequent layer. For example, if I add a linear activation layer (by uncommenting the block above), I'll get the following error:

```
Input 'surviving_indices' of layer 'identity' not found in any of the outputs of the preceding layers.
```

I have the same problem if I use the `box_count` output (i.e., by setting `input_name="box_count"` in the `add_activation` layer).

I know that the NMS layer is correctly returning outputs named `surviving_indices` and `box_count`, because when I call `print(builder.spec.neuralNetwork.layers[0])` I get the following result:

```
name: "nms"
input: "boxes"
input: "scores"
output: "nms_coords"
output: "nms_scores"
output: "surviving_indices"
output: "box_count"
NonMaximumSuppression {
  iouThreshold: 0.5
  scoreThreshold: 0.5
  maxBoxes: 3
}
```

Furthermore, if I use either the `nms_coords` or the `nms_scores` outputs as an input to the linear activation layer, I don't have any problems. It will correctly output the unmodified `nms_coords` or `nms_scores` values from the NMS layer's output.

I'm baffled as to why the NMS layer correctly outputs what I want it to, but then I'm unable to use those outputs in subsequent layers.

Comment: This appears to happen because you've also make `surviving_indices` an output of the model. If you do, `del builder.spec.description.output[2]`, the linear layer does get hooked up to the NMS layer. You still get the warning message, though. (It's possible this is an issue with the Core ML compiler.)

Comment: Thanks for the input, @MatthijsHollemans! I ended up opening an issue on the CoreMLTools GitHub page, and Apple responded. It seems like it's a bug on their end, and they're addressing it. 

See here:
https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/691#event-3295066804

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been fixed. Upgrade with

`pip install coremltools>=5.0b3`

From this comment made by a CoreMLTools team member:

- https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/691#issuecomment-900673764

> My macOS is 11.3 and I'm using coremltools version 5.0b3.
>
> Please verify that everything is fixed. Please pip install coremltools==5.0b3 on Big Sur or a Monterey beta, then verify you are no longer seeing this bug.